# Hiding non-member functions in header files

Tags: c++, templates

I'm wondering if I can define some functions in a header file and then use them in the same header file, while hiding them from anything else?

For example, can I first define some general helper functions(specific to the data-structures), and then define some data-structures in the same header that use those functions?

eg:

```
template<class T>
void Swap(T &a, T &b)
{
  T temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
```

But I don't want `Swap()` to interfere with other functions that have the same name.

I could make it a private method, but then I'd have to provide every class that uses it with the same implementation or make them friend class...

Comment: Concerning Swap interfering with other swap functions, that's why namespaces were invented, use them!  As far as I know, you can only hide functions in the header file by making them private inside of a class or a struct.  You could make a struct with just this function as a private, and specify the class you're making as a friend class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You usually can't hide the function completely from other clients but you can put it in its own namespace so that it doesn't interfere with client code. A common practice is to make the namespace an inner namespace of your main library namespace and to call it `details` or something similar.

Of course, if you need to function to be available through ADL then it *has* to live in the namespace enclosing the classes for which the ADL is supposed to match. There's no way around this.

Answer (score 8):

Traditionally, the namespace `details` is used for implementation-reserved stuff that has to go in a header.

Also, there's a `std::swap`, so no need for your own.